# Is there a relationship between maximum flow rate of a fluid through perforations in a cavity and the flow rate of the fluid in the cavity itself?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow, fluid-statics

I have a scenario where water is flowing horizontally through a (rectangular) cavity.  The *underside* of the cavity has a set of perforations that look something like:

[image: Perforations]

and I need to determine the maximum flow rate of water through the perforations.

How does (if it does) this flow rate depend on the flow rate and pressure of the water that's moving horizontally through the cavity?  Calculating flow rate through the perforations based on static water in the cavity is straightforward, but I am trying to understand the result when the flow is dynamic.

Comment: In my opinion it will make little difference whether the water is stationary or moving. The 'straightforward' case is based on stationary water but in the case of horizontal flow the boundary layer at the bottom is also supposed to be of very low speed, certainly in the case of laminar flow.

Comment: Intuitively I assumed that all else being equal, water of higher flow rate and pressure traveling through the cavity would result in a greater flow rate out of the perforations than would water of lower flow rate and pressure...?